# Why are the consequences of exploiting the "Unlimited" clauses in product offers?

Tags: licensing

There's a software application template and in its license (that is valid "forever"), they state that with the most advanced plan there's an "unlimited" amount of repository users available:

[image]
[image]

For the sake of my question, let us assume that there's no clause in their terms & conditions defining the limit on the "unlimited" and "forever", and take those two words as they are.

Now the question is, what could happen to me legally, as a user, if:

1. I purchase their license.
2. I start running a script to add new users to the repository, infinitely.

This action would at one point result either in an outage of their service, or they'd need to pay for data storage more than they earned by selling me the license.

I can imagine they would somehow find a way to cancel the license - give me back my money and cut off the access, effectively stopping the damage.

What would be the legal consequences I as a customer could suffer afterwards, what can they sue me for?

Comment: Probably covered in other terms of service? Most I've "carefully" read through have mentioned not sabotaging the service, and the way you worded #2 sounds more like sabotage than unconventional use.

Comment: @DanGetz indeed, and there could also be a requirement to have no more than one account per user and to have exactly one user who is an actual person associated with each account.

Comment: I do not believe this is an RSLA, because while it includes a specific example, it is asking a general question about the legal meaning of the word "unlimited."

Comment: And "forever", too. Thanks.